# How to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${f_n}$  be a sequence of  polynomial  with  real coefficients defined by $f_0 = 0$ and for $n= 0,1,2,\ldots$
$$f_{n+1}(x)  = f_n(x)  +  \frac {{x^2} -f_n^2(x)}{2}$$ 
Find $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n$  on $[-1,1]$, where the limit is taken in the supremum norm of $f_n $ over the interval $[-1,1]$.

My  answer  is   $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n$  $=0$ as it already  given that $f_0  =0$

EDIT: $$f_1 = f_0+ \frac {x^2 -f_0}{2}$$  as $f_1 = \frac {x^2}{2} $ and, similarly,  $f_2 =x^2 -\frac{x^2}{8}$

As I am not able  to proceed further as I don't know how to approach this question, please help me

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/505767/gimusi

Comment: If $f_{n+1}(x)$ converges to a limit, so should $f_n(x)$ and both limit are equal. This should do the trick.

Comment: im not getting@quallenjäger

Comment: @Stupid you forgot square in your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f_n=l,$ then also $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f_{n+1}=l$. So $$f_{n+1}(x)  = f_n(x)  +  \frac {{x^2} -f_n^2(x)}{2}\implies l=l+\frac{x^2-l^2}{2}$$

Comment: presumably that should be $l(x)$, also why can you suppose the limit exists in the first place?

Comment: that  mean  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n = 1$   am  i right???? @Lorenzo

Comment: @Stupid No, the limit is $|x|$.

Comment: thanks  lots @i707107